# An efficient way to track user login dates and IPs history

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to track user login history for stat purposes but its not clear to me what the best way to go about it would be. I could have a separate table that records users and their login stats with a date, but that table could get REALLY big. I could track some historic fields in the User model/object itself in a parse-able field and just update it (them) with some delimited string format. e.g. split on :, get the last one, if an included date code isn't today, add an item (date+count) otherwise increment, then save it back. At least with this second approach it would be easy to remove old items (e.g. only keep 30 days of daily logins, or IPs), as a separate table would require a task to delete old records.

I'm a big fan of instant changes. Tasks are useful, but can complicate things for maintenance reasons.

Anyone have any suggestions? I don't have an external data caching solution up or anything yet. Any pointers are also welcome! (I've been hunting for similar questions and answers)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate answering my own questions, especially given that you both gave helpful answers. I think answering my question with the approach I took might help others, in combination with your answers.

I've been playing with the [Impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) Gem (the only useful page view Gem since the abandoned RailStat) with good results so far. After setting up the basic migration, I found that the expected usage follows Rail's MVC design very closely. If you add "impressionist" to a Controller, it will go looking for the Model when logging the page view to the database. You can modify this behaviour or just call impressionist yourself in your Controller (or anywhere really) if you're like me and happen to be testing it out on a Controller that doesn't have a Model.

Anyways, I got it working with Devise to track successful logins by overriding the Devise::SessionsController and just calling the impressionist method for the @current_member: (don't forget to check if it's nil! on failed login)

```
class TestSessionController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    if not @current_member.nil?
      impressionist(@current_member)
    end
    super
  end
end
```

Adding it to other site parts later for some limited analytics is easy to do. The only other thing I had to do was update my routes to use the new TestSessionController for the Devise login route:

```
post 'login' => 'test_session#create', :as => :member_session
```

Devise works like normal without having to modify Devise in anyway, and my impressionist DB table is indexed and logging logins. I'll just need a rake task later to trim it weekly or so.

Now I just need to work out how to chart daily logins without having to write a bunch of looping, dirty queries...

Comment: It is ok, even encouraged, to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 8):

If you have the :trackable module, I found this the easiest way. In the User model (or whichever model you're authenticating)

```
  def update_tracked_fields!(request)
    old_signin = self.last_sign_in_at
    super
    if self.last_sign_in_at != old_signin
      Audit.create :user => self, :action => "login", :ip => self.last_sign_in_ip
    end
  end
```

(Inspired by https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Turn-off-trackable-for-admin-users)

Comment: This happens to be exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice way to do that through Devise.

Warden sets up a hook called after_set_user that runs after setting a user. So, supposed you have a model Login containing an ip field, a logged_in_at field and user_id field, you can only create the record using this fields.

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user :except => :fetch do |record, warden, options|
  Login.create!(:ip => warden.request.ip, :logged_in_at => Time.now, :user_id => record.id)
end
```

Comment: Be aware that this will be called on each request, since Devise also calls Warden's `set_user` when restoring the current user from the session. A better approach would probably to look for an existing record (e.g. based on the session id) and update it as necessary.

Comment: Also I just noticed you can check for `warden.winning_strategy`, it seems to always be `nil` when restoring from session.

Answer (score 5):

Building upon [@user208769's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20276850/107277), the core `Devise::Models::Trackable#update_tracked_fields!` method now calls a helper method named `update_tracked_fields` prior to saving.  That means you can use `ActiveRecord::Dirty` helpers to make it a little simpler:

```
def update_tracked_fields(request)
  super

  if last_sign_in_at_changed?
    Audit.create(user: self, action: 'login', ip: last_sign_in_ip)
  end
end
```

This can be simplified even further (and be more reliable given validations) if `audits` is a relationship on your model:

```
def update_tracked_fields(request)
  super
  audits.build(action: 'login', ip: last_sign_in_ip) if last_sign_in_at_changed?
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Devise supports tracking the last signed in date and the last signed in ip address with it's `:trackable` module. By adding this module to your user model, and then also adding the correct fields to your database, which are:

```
:sign_in_count,      :type => Integer, :default => 0
:current_sign_in_at, :type => Time
:last_sign_in_at,    :type => Time
:current_sign_in_ip, :type => String
:last_sign_in_ip,    :type => String
```

You could then override the `Devise::SessionsController` and it's `create` action to then save the `:last_sign_in_at` and `:last_sign_in_ip` to a separate table in a `before_create` callback. You should then be able to keep them as long you would like.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example (scribd_analytics)

```
create_table 'page_views' do |t|
  t.column 'user_id', :integer 
  t.column 'request_url', :string, :limit => 200
  t.column 'session', :string, :limit => 32
  t.column 'ip_address', :string, :limit => 16
  t.column 'referer', :string, :limit => 200
  t.column 'user_agent', :string, :limit => 200
  t.column 'created_at', :timestamp
end
```

> Add a whole bunch of indexes, depending on queries
>
> Create a PageView on every request
>
> We used a hand-built SQL query to take out the ActiveRecord overhead on
>   this
>
> Might try MySQL's 'insert delayed´
>
> Analytics queries are usually hand-coded SQL
>
> Use 'explain select´ to make sure MySQL isusing the indexes you expect
>
> Scales pretty well
>
> BUT analytics queries expensive, can clog upmain DB server
>
> **Our solution:**
>
> ```
> use two DB servers in a master/slave setup
>
> move all the analytics queries to the slave
> ```

http://www.scribd.com/doc/49575/Scaling-Rails-Presentation-From-Scribd-Launch

---

Another option to check is Gattica with Google Analytics

Comment: That preso has given me a lot to think about. However it is more serious than I was initially planning. A master/slave DB isn't possible when hosting at Heroku. Also I'd like to access the stats from my Web app, like a dashboard. I think I'll create a page view table for now and worry about the stress points when I'm more familiar with a working solution. It's possible I might have to setup a rake task to query pre-arranged stats nightly or something into easy to read data during repeated requests. e.g. like an IP map from a dashboard that gets viewed 1000 times a day.

Answer (score 0):

There is also ['paper_trail' gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail), that allows to track model changes.