# Rails - Tracing user connection with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to trace the user's devise connection in a history table.
Just a basic table with user_id, login_time, logout_time.

Do you know any gem that to this work? (devise_traceable is realy close of what I want but no more supported, have some errors and add login time only when user logout).

I there is no gem for that, do you have a idea how to extend devise to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Trackable

Comment: This is not a historic log.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500653/an-efficient-way-to-track-user-login-dates-and-ips-history

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've find how to do it with Warden

In devise.rb :

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user, auth, opts|
    ... create trace here ...
end
Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts| 
    ... stop trace here ...
end
```