# What is the best way to track all Devise logins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My current thoughts are to override the sessions create method, have a has_many association to a user_logins model and log all session creations. Though, I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

```
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
```

Could I just slip in `User_Logins.create(:date => current_sign_in_at, :ip => current_sign_in_ip)` - Presumably after the `sign_in(resource_name, resource)` method is called so that the current attributes have been updated.

Any thoughts would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Devise provides a method call that you can use to execute some code after successful sign in.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    UserLogin.create(:date => Date.today, :ip => request.remote_ip, :user_id => current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Note that I've called the model "UserLogin" which would by default map to a table called "user_logins" which is more convention-over-configuration.

Comment: that's to define the url that is redirected to after login, not a callback to add logging etc.. it will technically work I guess but pretty hackish.

Comment: How about these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500653/an-efficient-way-to-track-user-login-dates-and-ips-history